# Node JS taking long time in sending initial data

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I am facing an issue with NodeJS. Initially it takes a long time about 4-5 seconds before I get any update. Node JS Server is publicly accessible and it is not patched through any proxy or anything. But once initial connection has been established - updates are instantaneous.

I dug deep using network tools from Chrome - it says it is waiting for data. see the attached image

I am also pasting the code for my app.js (node application) for your reference.

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    amqp = require('amqp'),
    sys = require(process.binding('natives').util ? 'util' : 'sys');
var exchangeName = 'conferenceTest';
send404 = function (res) {
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.write('404');
  res.end();
};
server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  switch (path) {
  case '/':
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/index.html", function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        return send404(res);
      } else {
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
          'Connection': 'close',
          'content-encoding': 'gzip'
        });
        res.write(data, 'utf8');
        res.end();
      }
    });
    break;
  }
});
// listen to the http server for socket connections
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var connection = amqp.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost'
});
connection.on('ready', function () {
  var exchange = connection.exchange(exchangeName, { // create exchange
    type: 'direct',
    durable: true
  });
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    console.log("client connected");
    client.on('changeview', function (data) {
      var queue = connection.queue(data.queueName, { //create queue
        durable: true,
        autoDelete: false
      });
      var plaintext = "Put any kind of meat on a stick and roast it over a flame and it immediately becomes food fit for gods. No country understands this sacred rule of seared meat like Turkey.Turkish kebabs are the incarnation of the meat lovers most exotic fantasies, with grilled lamb, beef and chicken as skewer MVPs.Most kebab restaurants also have a long list of Turkish starters called meze that are as delicious as the main dishes.Turkeys best alcoholic complement for all that meat is raki -- an aniseed-flavored drink that s often diluted with water and chilled with ice. Frothy, yogurt-based ayran is a great non-alcoholic complement to heavy dishes. But who are we kidding -- you just want the meat. Heres where to get it in Turkey.";
      io.sockets.emit('changeview', plaintext);
    });
  });
});
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log('Uncaught Exception: ' + err.message);
});
server.listen(18080);
```

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It could be your machine or your network.

Comment: hmmmmm - this id what i suspect - I am running behind pf-sense and squid set up.  I will try this at home

Answer (score 1):

Your client is requesting some long numerical URI, but your handler is only accepting requests for `/` (for which it sends back `index.html`). Other requests (like for the numerical URI's) are just not handled at all, which means your browser will wait for some time and eventually give up.

To solve, add a default case and return a `404` error:

```
switch (path) {
  case '/':
    // your current code
    break;
  default:
    send404(res);
}
```

Also: why are you setting those specific headers on the response for the `index.html` file? `application/zip` would mean that your `index.html` should be regarded as a ZIP file, and setting the content encoding to `gzip` would mean that the response is gzip'ed. Neither of which seem to be the case here.

Comment: No i didn't noticed any improvement in the response - it is the same. Please ignore the content-type header declaration for application/zip it is leftover from zlib testing

Comment: Could it be related to your AMQP setup? I just realized that the numerical URI's could be generated/handled by `socket.io`.

Comment: hmmmmm or probably as Joseph pointed out early - it might be because of network - i will test it at home

Answer (score 0):

On the **client side** - default connect timeout is 10 seconds

I have reduced it to 500 ms - it connects almost now in 2.92 seconds - previously it was taking up to 12.3 seconds

```
var conn = io.connect("http://myserver.com:myport/", { transports: transports, 'reconnect': true, 'connect timeout':500});
```

Hope it helps anyone else struggling with this issue